# In wiki-pages, how to link to a local folder or document?

Tags: hyperlink

How does one create a link to a "local" folder or document in wiki pages?

In internet explorer, word, excel, etc. this is a valid link: `file://X:\Some\Folder\Foobar.xls`.

However in Sharepoint the only part linkified is `file://`. Furthermore when using the *Insert Link* ([ctrl-k]) dialog I'm told file:// is an invalid protocol.

UNC paths work, but the whole point of using drive letters (for us) is to turn `\\server\share\big\long\path\to\resource` into `X:\resource`. Something people are not going to give up willingly.

Answer (score 2):

Ahh, found it. Links must use fore-slashes, `file://X:/Some/Folder/Foobar.xls`.

Annoying because one can't simply copy-n-paste from a Windows Explorer address bar, but at least it works.

Comment: Are you sure everyone will have the same server mapped to the same drive? If not, this will blow up and not server the file. UNC path would be preferred.

Comment: @PirateEric, yes there are handful of drive letters that are mandated to be the same across the whole department, enforced by login scripts. *X:\thing* is definitely preferential to *\\ServerThree\corporate\thing*. This allows replacing the server underneath, and links from 10 years and 3 servers ago still work.